# Reason of error "Application not installed"

Tags: android

I have very basic application with single MainActivy class that has only one default method `onCreate` . Trying to build APK application by using Gradle. I do `Edit Configurations -> Add New Configuration -> Gradle -> Gradle project - Minimas; Task - assemble.`

Gradle build without errors and I got `app-release-unsigned.apk` file. I placed file in Ggrive and run in my Samsung S8. Installing from Gdrive is allowed.
Application was asking `Do you want to install this application? It does not require any special access.` -> `Install`. And finally I got message `App not installed`.

Why it is not installed? How to know problem and how to solve it? Is it possible to get any log file in order to know reason?

UPD

Application uploads and runs through Android Studio just fine, but I need to creat working apk file.

Comment: I got this issue when the same application is already installed and you are installing another same one with few minor changes like debug and release or vice versa.

Comment: Hi @vico, have you tried building it this way: build->build debugable apk. You will get debuggable apk that you can install. Or you can switch directly to developer mode on your device and upload code through android studio

Comment: Through Android Studio it uploads and runs fine. But I need prepare apk file. I build and was trying to install debugable application, but got the same result. Where debugable application logs information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install unsigned APKs. You'll have to sign the APK - you have [a few options](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) for how to do that.